# How to check if menu is assigned and not empty in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a big issue with menu in WordPress,
I'm trying to check if menu assigned by:

```
if(has_nav_menu('main-menu')) {
  echo 'assigned';
} else {
  echo 'no';
}
```

and it is working, but I also want to check if it is assigned and is not empty,
because if I choose menu in admin panel without any item I'll get `assigned` in my condition.

Can someone help me, please? I found some questions about this, but there is no answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `wp_nav_menu` with the `echo` param set to `false` to check if the menu is empty like below:

```
// check if menu is empty or not
$has_menu_items = wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu', 'echo' => false )) !== false;

// check if menu location is assigned
$is_assigned = has_nav_menu('main-menu');

// check for both conditions
if($has_menu_items && $is_assigned) {
  echo 'assigned';
} else {
  echo 'no';
}
```